# access a page in the MVC Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to redirect to a page in the case that does not accomplish a condition
in the global.asax in method application start... redirects to a warning page like this:...

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    if (MyClass.Warnning == "2")
    {
       Response.Redirect("~/warningPage.aspx");
    }
}
```

but it shows me the following error:

> response HttpException unavailable in this context...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Brad mentioned, `Application_Start` isn't the appropriate place for a redirect since ASP is just spinning up.

One option would be to have a separate method that performs your checks and throws an exception if it does not succeed.  You can then handle the exception in your `Application_Error` method in the Global.asax.

Answer (score 2):

`Application_Start` isn't under the context of a request, it's the site spinning up.

You should be looking at something like `Application_BeginRequest` or, better yet, looking at using an ActionFilter (since you're tagging MVC).